# rpm verify - ignore config files

Tags: linux, rpm, verify

From `man rpm`

> rpm {-V|--verify} [select-options] [verify-options]

Files that have been changed after installation will be listed by this [rpm verify](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-verify-output.html) command.

But this lists the configuration files also (files that are marked with `%config` in this `spec` file.

Is there a way to skip/ignore the verification for the `config` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes and no:

- I don't know any method for ignoring some files with `rpm -V`
- But in your spec file you can add `verify` attributes for some files to specify how they should be verified.

This way you could specify for example to check only the owner and group of your config file:

```
%verify(owner group) /path/to/your/config-file
```

for further reference; look here: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html

Comment: Thanks. Will do that when building an RPM next time. I was looking to verify released RPMs. But looks like there isn't any such option.